# Blazor linter problem when inheriting a component

Tags: visual-studio, inheritance, blazor, resharper, rider

i have a simple component called
*BaseGrid.razor*

and then I have another component called
*CustomGrid.razor*

```
@inherits BaseGrid

...

@{
    base.BuildRenderTree(__builder);
}

...
```

when using Rider __builder gets marked in red saying

> cannot resolve symbol '__builder'

but the project builds just fine

this problem also occur when using ReSharper with Visual Studio

i don't know if its a ReShaper problem or Visual Studio does this too but seeing all the files underlined in red is giving me an headache when trying to find with files have a real problem

Comment: I have had similar issues of late with visual studio and Razor components.  I don't think Visual Studio, Razor, the compiler, and whatever other processes are involved are on the same page at the moment.

Comment: so I should just wait until they all get used to Blazor?

Comment: See my answer below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your case the problem is that the Razor compiler manages to interpret what you've coded and by chance work.  In the code view Visual Studio has no idea that __builder exists: it only exists in the C# class the Razor compiler builds from the Razor file.

Here's my version of what you've shown us that is "more" syntactically correct (not sure that's the right expression but its the best I can think of now).  It doesn't throw errors because Visual Studio understands the concept of a `RenderFragment`.

### BaseGrid

```
<h3>BaseGrid</h3>

@code {
}
```

### Grid

I assign to base `BuildRenderTree` method to a `RenderFragment` delegate and then set the component to render the render fragment.

```
@inherits BaseGrid
<h3>Grid</h3>

@baseRenderFragment

@code {
    RenderFragment? baseRenderFragment;

    protected override void OnInitialized()
    {
        baseRenderFragment = base.BuildRenderTree;
    }
}
```

Which then looks like this:

[image]